# How to use union in DAC loopup?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

How to use Union in DAC lookup fields?

I want to get all DISTINCT FromUnit and ToUnit data by joining them to show in lookup how may i do this?

for example:
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT FromUnit FROM INUnit UNION  SELECT ToUnit FROM INUnit) AS UNIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid doing an UNION query and instead look for global entries (`INUnitType.global`) that have from unit == to unit:

```
[PXDBString(6, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaa")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Test")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<INUnit.fromUnit, Where<INUnit.unitType, Equal<INUnitType.global>, And<INUnit.fromUnit, Equal<INUnit.toUnit>>>>), typeof(INUnit.fromUnit))]]]>
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWFzK.jpg

Comment: I want to use it in DAC lookup, will it give all from and ToUnit with distinct Entries?

Comment: Yes, since all the combinations already exist at the global level

Comment: How may i bind DAC property from, FromUnit or To Unit?

Comment: Are you trying to build a selector?

Comment: Yes. I have a field in DAC, I want to make to add selector on it show all From/ToUnit.

Comment: Can you share the current declaration/attributes of the field? That will be easier.

Comment: I want to show From and To unit both, and whatever value is selected, should bind to Unit.

[PXSelector(typeof(Search4<INUnit.fromUnit, Aggregate<GroupBy<INUnit.fromUnit>>>), typeof(INUnit.fromUnit), SubstituteKey = typeof(INUnit.fromUnit))]
        public virtual string Unit {
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: @user_mat I updated my answer to show the actual attributes you need to use this as part of a selector.